# gcloud SSL Handshake fail with zscaler

Tags: ssl, gcloud, ca, man-in-the-middle, zscaler

I'm using `gcloud` to deploy apps to App Engine from a machine that has ZScaler internet filter installed on it. I'm not familiar with ZScaler but it looks like it's a filter installed on Windows and essentially does a "man-in-the-middle" attach by providing "false" digital certificates signed by ZScaler CA and the root CA certificates of ZScaler were installed trusted root CA.

My question is - is it possible to run `gcloud` with security turned off?

This is the output I get from `gcloud info --run-diagnostics`:

```
Network diagnostic detects and fixes local network connection issues.
Checking network connection...done.
ERROR: Reachability Check failed.
    Cannot reach https://www.google.com (SSLHandshakeError)
    Cannot reach https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/components-2.json (SSLHandshakeError)
Network connection problems may be due to proxy or firewall settings
```

Comment: you might need to add these certificates locally & remotely, so that the authenticity can be confirmed. this appears relevant: https://help.zscaler.com/zpa/documentation-knowledgebase/certificates ...forget about "running gcloud with security turned off" - rather bypass ZScaler for that destination, if possible.

Comment: you have to contact your network security admins responsible for Zscaler to bypass SSL inspection for mentioned google domains

Answer (score 0):

This is a fix that worked for me for Zscaler proxy:

I got a copy of the ZScaler Root CA certificate from my local machine and exported it to a base64 file, call it certfile.cer.
I then configured gcloud with the following settings:

`gcloud config set proxy/type http`
`gcloud config set proxy/address corpproxy.local`
`gcloud config set proxy/port 80`
`gcloud config set core/custom_ca_certs_file C:\certs\certfile.cer`

Obviously replace corpproxy.local with your corporate proxy and the correct path to your certificate file.